# Object reactor "copied" and "modified" in one entity going wrong - Help needed

Tags: lisp, autocad, autocad-plugin, autolisp

My intent is to create some lines having two texts each with short info (made as a group), and letting the reactor assigned to the line making sure that:

1. When copied, the handles of each entity will get updated with the info of the others and
2. In case I stretch the line using the end grip, the line reactor will update the length of the line as stored xdata and updating the text value that corresponds to the length.

So far and with the valuable help of this forum I was able to make it with the copy part of the story. When I try to incorporate the 'modified' option in the reactor, it does not work. Below is the code I use.

The first function assigns the reactor to the line during its creation through an other function, not shown here. The rest are callbacks and so on. Any suggestions appreciated.

In continuation to this question:

[How to update xdata information of an entity when it is copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840278/how-to-update-xdata-information-of-an-entity-when-it-is-copied)

```
(defun assign_LLreactor (LL_ename LL_Length LL_Size / LL_ename LL_hLength LL_hSize)
    (if (= 'vlr-object-reactor (type lineReactor))      
        (vlr-owner-add lineReactor (vlax-ename->vla-object LL_ename))
        (vlr-set-notification
            (setq lineReactor
                (vlr-object-reactor (list (vlax-ename->vla-object LL_ename)) "Line Reactor"
                    '(
                        (:vlr-modified . LL_callback_mod)
                        (:vlr-copied . LL_callback)
                    )
                )
            )
            'active-document-only
        )
    )

    (makeagroup (ssadd (handent LL_Length) (ssadd (handent LL_Size) (ssadd LL_ename (ssadd)))))
)

(defun LL_callback (notifierobj reactorobj paramls)
    (if (/= 0 (car paramls))
        (progn
            (setq LL_owner (append LL_owner (list (car paramls))))
            (vlr-command-reactor "LL_copied_re"
               '(
                    (:vlr-commandended     . LL_copyended)
                    (:vlr-commandcancelled . LL_copycancelled)
                    (:vlr-commandfailed    . LL_copycancelled)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

(defun LL_callback_mod (owner reactorobj paramls)
    (setq LL_owner (append LL_owner (list owner)))
    (vlr-command-reactor "LL_modified_re"
       '(
            (:vlr-commandended     . LL_modifiedended)
            (:vlr-commandcancelled . LL_modifiedcancelled)
            (:vlr-commandfailed    . LL_modifiedcancelled)
        )
    )
)

(defun LL_copyended ( reactor params / enametxt txt1 txt2 hSize hLength groupedentities txthandles grtxtdata)
    (vlr-remove reactor)

    (if
        (and
            (setq LL_ent (car LL_owner))
            (setq LL_enx (entget LL_ent '("LL_U")))
            (= (cdr (assoc 0 LL_enx)) "LINE")
            (setq LL_3data (assoc -3 LL_enx))
        )
        (progn
            (foreach n (setq groupedentities (_groupedenames LL_ent))
                (if (= (cdr (assoc 0 (setq grtxtdata (entget n '("LL_U"))))) "TEXT")
                    (progn
                        (setq txthandles (append txthandles (list (cdr (assoc 5 grtxtdata)))))
                        (entmod (subst (list -3 (list "LL_U" (cons 1005 (cdr (assoc 5 LL_enx))))) (assoc -3 grtxtdata) grtxtdata))
                    )
                )
            )
            (setq txthandles (vl-sort txthandles (function (lambda (a b) (< a b)))))
            (entmod (subst (list -3 (list "LL_U" (cons 1005 (cadr txthandles)) (cons 1005 (car txthandles)))) (assoc -3 LL_enx) LL_enx))
        )
    )

    (if (and LL_enx (= 'vlr-object-reactor (type lineReactor)))
        (vlr-owner-add lineReactor (vlax-ename->vla-object LL_ent))
    )

    (setq LL_owner (cdr LL_owner))
    (princ)
)

(defun LL_modifiedended ( reactor params / LL_ent LL_enx llpt10 llpt11 LL_3data LL_3data_n)
    (if
        (and
            (setq LL_ent (car LL_owner))
            (setq LL_enx (entget LL_ent '("Pdata")))
            (= (cdr (assoc 0 LL_enx)) "LINE")
            (setq LL_3data (assoc -3 LL_enx))
        )
        (progn
            (if (= 'vlr-object-reactor (type lineReactor))
                (vlr-remove lineReactor)
            )
            (setq llpt10 (cdr (assoc 10 LL_enx)))
            (setq llpt11 (cdr (assoc 11 LL_enx)))
            (setq LL_3data_n (list -3 (subst (cons 1000 (rtos (distance llpt10 llpt11) 2 3)) (nth 2 (cadr LL_3data)) (cadr LL_3data))))
            (ht_ss (ssadd (cdr (assoc -1 (entmod (subst LL_3data_n (assoc -3 LL_enx) LL_enx)))) (ssadd)))

            (if (= 'vlr-object-reactor (type lineReactor))
                (vlr-add lineReactor)
            )
        )
    )
    (princ)
)

(defun LL_copycancelled ( reactor params )
    (vlr-remove reactor)
    (setq LL_owner nil)
    (princ)
)

(defun LL_modifiedcancelled ( reactor params )
    (vlr-remove reactor)
    (setq LL_owner nil)
    (princ)
)
```

I expect the object reactor works well for both 'modified' and 'copied' action for lines being either stretched or copied with updated xdata and texts.

Comment: After a cursory glance, it doesn't look like you are updating the content of the text objects, only updating the xdata.

Comment: The ht_ss function (not shown here) is responsible to do that. It only changes the xdata along with placing the texts on the correct location. A visual representation of the line and texts can be seen at the link below. The function requires a ss which parse through the lines in the ss to update text. https://www.cadtutor.net/forum/topic/68098-reactor-when-entity-copied-how-to-pass-the-ss/

Comment: Also, the 'makeagroup' in the 'assign_LLreactor' function function just creates an anonymous group containing the line and the two texts.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve the issue by utilizing a separate list for the owners of the specific reactor type (e.g. 'copied' or 'modified'). So 'LL_owner' list became two, 'LL_copy_owner' and 'LL_mod_owner'. Now it works fine (until further notice :).